# Combine date and time to a datetime

Tags: date, datetime, time, elixir, timex

How can I convert a `Date` and a `Time` to a `DateTime`?

Say I have the following `date` and `time`

```
iex> date = ~D[2018-01-01]
iex> time = ~T[00:00:01.000]
```

How can I combine these to output the `datetime`: `#DateTime<2018-01-01 00:00:01Z>` in a clean way?

The best I come up with is using the [`Timex` library](https://hexdocs.pm/timex/Timex.html):

```
Timex.add(Timex.to_datetime(date), Timex.Duration.from_time(time))
```

but I feel that surely there is a nicer, more readable way to combine this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using the [calendar](https://hexdocs.pm/calendar/) library, you can use either the [Calendar.DateTime.from_date_and_time_and_zone](https://hexdocs.pm/calendar/Calendar.DateTime.html#from_date_and_time_and_zone/3) function or the [Calendar.NaiveDateTime.from_date_and_time](https://hexdocs.pm/calendar/Calendar.NaiveDateTime.html#from_date_and_time/2) function:

```
iex(4)> Calendar.DateTime.from_date_and_time_and_zone(~D[2018-10-01], ~T[12:22:22], "Australia/Melbourne")
{:ok, #DateTime<2018-10-01 12:22:22+10:00 AEST Australia/Melbourne>}
iex(5)> Calendar.NaiveDateTime.from_date_and_time(~D[2018-10-01], ~T[12:22:22])                           
{:ok, ~N[2018-10-01 12:22:22]}
```

There are also [from_date_and_time!](https://hexdocs.pm/calendar/Calendar.NaiveDateTime.html#from_date_and_time!/2) and [from_date_and_time!](https://hexdocs.pm/calendar/Calendar.NaiveDateTime.html#from_date_and_time!/2) variants.

Comment: Although it's not using `Timex, it's doing exactly what I was after

Comment: Your linked github issue suggests this issue is now resolved in Timex. Additionally, Timex delegates to Calendar now for most operations now.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I didn't followup, but pretty sure I tested and had no issues anymore. I deleted that paragraph.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`NaiveDateTime.new/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/NaiveDateTime.html#new/2):

```
iex> NaiveDateTime.new(date, time)
{:ok, ~N[2018-01-01 00:00:01.000]}
```

The reason it is a "naive datetime" instead of a datetime is that the `Time` struct doesn't contain time zone information.  If you know the time zone, you can add that information using [`DateTime.from_naive/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/DateTime.html#from_naive/3):

```
iex> DateTime.from_naive(~N[2018-01-01 00:00:01.000], "Etc/UTC")
{:ok, #DateTime<2018-01-01 00:00:01.000Z>}
```

Comment: This is quite nice (and seems like the best option out there), but I would like it if there was the option to not need to handle the `:ok`, `:error` tuple pattern

Comment: `from_naive!/1`

Answer (score 3):

While the answer by @legoscia is perfectly valid, here is how you deal with *date and time pair* (without `Timex`, just pure Elixir standard library):

```rb
date = ~D[2018-01-01]
time = ~T[00:00:01.000]

{Date.to_erl(date), Time.to_erl(time)}
|> NaiveDateTime.from_erl!()
|> DateTime.from_naive("Etc/UTC")
#⇒ {:ok, #DateTime<2018-01-01 00:00:01Z>}
```

Comment: Thanks +1, good one to know, but I think I slightly prefer @legoscia's answer (and he got there first).